# File "BundleSDF-master/bundlesdf.py", line ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_cpp

Tags: python, bundle

```
Appeared when running the command python run_ho3d.py --video_dirs /home/huangcheng/hou/BundleSDF/BundleSDF-master/HO3D_v3/evaluation/MPM10 --out_dir /home/huangcheng/hou/BundleSDF/BundleSDF-master/ho3d_our
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_ho3d.py", line 10, in &lt;module&gt;
    from bundlesdf import *
  File "/home/huangcheng/hou/BundleSDF/BundleSDF-master/bundlesdf.py", line 15, in &lt;module&gt;
    import my_cpp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_cpp'
```

I hope someone can help

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the script build.sh :
bash build.sh